# What kind of equation am I trying to make? (factoral with addition type of thing)

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial

So say I have a `y = 12`. Then I'd like to compute:

`(x*12)+(x*11)+(x*10)+(x*9)+(x*8)+(x*7)+(x*6)+(x*5)+(x*4)+(x*3)+(x*2)+(x*1)`

or say I have `y = 4`. Then I'd like to compute:

`(x*4)+(x*3)+(x*2)+(x*1)`

I'd like to know if there is a name for this type of equation and if there is a simpler way to write it. The reason I'd like to know is because I'm trying to do this in Excel with a y of 3,652 (and x is a cell reference). I wrote a python script that writes the formula for me but it crashes excel when I try to paste a forumula that long. Instead I'm looking for a cleaner way to do this type of math so I can translate that to Excel.

Comment: Factor out $x$ from the whole equation then use $\frac{n(n+1)}2$ formula to find the sum of the first $n$ integers. For example, $12x+11x+10x+\cdots+2x+x=(12+11+10+\cdots+2+1)x=\left(\frac{12(13)}{2}\right)x=78x$. I don't think there's a particular name for this kind of sum, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you factor $x$ out of your algorithm, you get

$$x(y+(y-1)+(y-2)... + \ 1)$$

What's in the brackets is an arithmetic series. The sum is given by the formula
$$\frac{n(a_1+a_n)}{2}$$

where $n$ is the number of terms, $a_1$ is the first term, and $a_n$ is the $n$th term. If you plug the values  of your series into the formula, you get

$$\frac{y(y+1)}{2}$$

Multiplying this by $x$ will give you the algorithm you want:

$$\frac{xy(y+1)}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

> $(x\cdot y)+...+(x\cdot2)+(x\cdot1)$

can be rewritten as

> $x(1 + 2 + ... + y)$ with $y = 4$.

Then $(1 + 2 + ... + y - 1 + y)$ is an [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) (starting with $1$ with $y$ elements and difference equal to $y$).

To get the sum of this arithmetic progression we can use .
$$y \cdot (y + 1) / 2$$

This comes from [$n \cdot (a_1 + a_n) / 2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum), where $n$ is the count of elements, $a_1$ is the first element, and $a_n$ is the $n$-th element (in our case, $y$)

What you search should be $x \cdot y \cdot (y + 1) / 2$.